# Como posso chamar funções que estão depois da mesma função?

Tags: python

Já consegui algumas vezes chamar funções que estão mais á frente no programa. No entanto, demoro horas para encontrar uma maneira de fazê-lo. Qual é a maneira mais fácil? Ex:

```
def paintball():
    print "Olá"
    adeus()

def adeus():
    print "Adeus"
```

É apenas uma forma simples de mostrar o problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto:

```
def paintball():
    print "Olá"
    adeus()

def adeus():
    print "Adeus"

paintball()
```

Funciona, afinal, `adeus()` está antes de `paintball()`, e a análise dos nomes das funções só é feita em tempo de execução.

Agora,

```
def paintball():
    print "Olá"
    adeus()

paintball()

def adeus():
    print "Adeus"
```

Isto é impossível de funcionar, porque no momento da execução, o nome `adeus()` não foi avaliado em um momento sequer.

Comment: Obrigado ;) Por causa de não fazer isso perco imenso tempo a tentar.